# Dependency Issue

Tags: ant, maven-2

I am trying to use Maven in Ant using the Maven Ant Tasks.  I have been able to install/dependencies custom libraries to a local repo (Artifactory) and have been able to get dependencies (from public repos and local).  I am running into an issue with a custom library and not sure where the issue lies.

1. Add library to local repo with new version
2. Get dependencies for project, including new library version <--- this works
3. Delete local .m2 repository cache.
4. Try to get dependencies again.  Everything from public repo is downloaded, but custom lib is not.  In fact, i need to either delete the version or create a new version to be able to download it again (and that would only work 1x).

The error i get is:
    [artifact:dependencies] An error has occurred while processing the Maven artifact  tasks.
    [artifact:dependencies]  Diagnosis:
    [artifact:dependencies] 
    [artifact:dependencies] Unable to resolve artifact: Missing:
    [artifact:dependencies] ----------
    [artifact:dependencies] 1) xxx.yyy:zzz:jar:0.0.2

The version still shows up in Artifactory, and I can see both the jar and pom.

My local cache does not have the jar (as I expect with the above error)

Comment: Not enough detail. How are you configuring the Maven tasks? Another "gotcha" is that the Maven tasks will make use of the standard Maven settings file, located in your "$HOME/.m2/settings.xml" file. Perhaps Maven is configured not to pick up jars from your Artifactory repository

Comment: That looks like using the wrong GAV coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as it turns out, the issue had to do with security configuration settings within artifactory.  the application didn't consistently allow public access to due improper configuration.